Ansible Extract Values from Output
I have a Web API call that grabs network device details and outputs a few different values. I would like to pull out the switch name and switch port from this output and register them seperately as variables for another task to call. I'm not sure how to accomplish this though.
Config:

<some task config omitted>
      register: spm_results

    - debug:
        var: spm_results.content

Output:
ok: [localhost] => {
    "spm_results.content": "00:1a:1e:cd:84:e2,Aruba a Hewlett Packard Enterprise Compa,M-1-DA,Gi3/0/4,prod,10.7.5.60\n"
}

I would like to match the switch name (M-1-DA in above output) based on this type of regex [a-zA-Z]-[0-999]-D[a-zA-Z] and the switchport by looking for ^Gi and register them both as different variables.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Unable to find specific required code to accomplish this

Couldn't you just use the from csv filter?  Something like this. {{ spm_results.content | community.general.from_csv(dialect='unix' fieldnames='hwaddress,company,Switch,SwitchPort,env,ip') }}

There are more options:

split the line. You can trim it first

  content: "{{ spm_results.content | trim | split(',') }}"

gives
  content:
  - 00:1a:1e:cd:84:e2
  - Aruba a Hewlett Packard Enterprise Compa
  - M-1-DA
  - Gi3/0/4
  - prod
  - 10.7.5.60

Then, the matching of the items is trivial
  mac: "{{ content.0 }}"
  vendor: "{{ content.1 }}"
  switch: "{{ content.2 }}"
  port: "{{ content.3 }}"
  env: "{{ content.4 }}"
  ip: "{{ content.5 }}"


Optionally, create a list of field names and use the filter   community.general.dict

  fieldnames: [mac, vendor, switch, port, env, ip]
  hw: "{{ content |
          zip(fieldnames) |
          map('reverse') |
          community.general.dict }}"

gives the dictionary
  hw:
    env: prod
    ip: 10.7.5.60
    mac: 00:1a:1e:cd:84:e2
    port: Gi3/0/4
    switch: M-1-DA
    vendor: Aruba a Hewlett Packard Enterprise Compa


The next option is the filter community.general.from_csv

  hw: "{{ spm_results.content |
          community.general.from_csv(dialect='unix', fieldnames=fieldnames) }}"

gives the list
  hw:
  - env: prod
    ip: 10.7.5.60
    mac: 00:1a:1e:cd:84:e2
    port: Gi3/0/4
    switch: M-1-DA
    vendor: Aruba a Hewlett Packard Enterprise Compa



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    spm_results:
      content: >
        00:1a:1e:cd:84:e2,Aruba a Hewlett Packard Enterprise Compa,M-1-DA,Gi3/0/4,prod,10.7.5.60

    content: "{{ spm_results.content | trim | split(',') }}"
    mac: "{{ content.0 }}"
    vendor: "{{ content.1 }}"
    switch: "{{ content.2 }}"
    port: "{{ content.3 }}"
    env: "{{ content.4 }}"
    ip: "{{ content.5 }}"

    fieldnames: [mac, vendor, switch, port, env, ip]
    hw: "{{ content |
            zip(fieldnames) |
            map('reverse') |
            community.general.dict }}"
    
    h2: "{{ spm_results.content |
            community.general.from_csv(dialect='unix', fieldnames=fieldnames) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: content
    - debug:
        var: switch

    - debug:
        var: hw

    - debug:
        var: h2


